# Spark: how long does it keep RDD in cache

Tags: caching, apache-spark, rdd

For example, I cached a number of RDDs in memory.

Then I leave the application for a few days or more.

And then I try to access cached RDDs.

**Will they still be in memory?**

Or Spark will clean unused cached RDDs after some period of time.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion. If you would like to manually remove an RDD instead of waiting for it to fall out of the cache, use the RDD.unpersist() method.

Comment: The driver program is not complete. It just wait/sleep/hang for a long time and then access RDDs.

Comment: what is your exact requirement , if you want to clear it, you can do it using unpersist().if you don't anything ,they will be available as long as your driver program has access to the spark context.

Comment: I want to use the RDDs cached more then day/month/year ago (the application is still running). In the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) I see: "Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion."  I need to know in which case or when the RDD will be dropped.

Comment: I believe there is no time limit for this , for example  you have cached 3 RDDs , out of 3 you are frequently accessing 2 , in this case , the one which which is not recently used will be dropped to make memory available for new RDDs to be cached.

Comment: Yes, I need to know when it will be dropped.

Comment: I don't believe you should be able to know that ,it all depends on how much memory allocated for in memory , if it is running out of memory , based on LRU basis ,it will remove the data , if you mention storage level as MEMORY_AND_DISK ,it will write it to disk.

Comment: @KaterynaKhotkevych: It will be dropped when another `RDD` or Computation needed space in RAM. Till that time RDD will be available in memory.

Comment: @ArunakiranNulu can you please cite the source of this information ?